# Wpf datagridrow contextmenu compilation error

Tags: c#, wpf

On this code:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Category.Reports}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
              Name="_gridReports" SelectedItem="{Binding Report}">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                            <MenuItem Header="Удалить" Click="OnDeleteClick" 
                                    IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsDefault, Converter={StaticResource toBoolConverter}}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Редактировать" Click="OnEditClick" 
                                    IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsDefault, Converter={StaticResource toBoolConverter}}" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Название" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description}" Header="Описание" IsReadOnly="True" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Compiler create nearly that error message (translating from russian, maybe some mistakes):

```
Invalid value "OnDeleteClick". "Click" is not event for "System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn"
```

Hope you will help me! Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the event into a style

```
<MenuItem Header="Удалить" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsDefault, Converter={StaticResource toBoolConverter}}">
    <MenuItem.Style>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="OnDeleteClick" />
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.Style>
</MenuItem>
```

or use Commands.

Comment: thanx a lot! this solved my problem, but now when program launched it throws exception: Unable to cast object type ...MenuItem to type ...DataGrid. Maybe you have answer for this too?

Comment: Sorry, I can't say without further information. Please ask a new question with the code throwing this exception.

Comment: Well, somehow, I solved that problem too) Thanx for help one more time!